# Crystal Reports renders differently with different display DPI sizes

Tags: crystal-reports, rendering, dpi

I designed my report in Visual Studio with display DPI size 100% (Windows 7).
In page setup dialog I chose a printer which all of my colleagues and all of our customers have installed with the same driver.

When I change the display size to 125% and open the report in Visual Studio it renders differently. Some text is now too wide for displaying in my text fields and are cut of. Generating the report ends with the same result (export to PDF).

I've read much about how important it is to have the same printer with the same drivers installed on all machines that run those reports and chosing that printer in the page setup dialog. But I've read nothing about how the display size is also having an influence of the report rendering.

How can I ensure that my reports render the same on all machines with all display settings possible? Please note, that I have no problem with different printers or drivers but only with different display resolutions.